# how do i display the value of a stopwatch reading to my screen

Tags: javascript

I have tried to work on these codes but it feels like I have gotten it all wrong. I am a JS beginner and tried on a stopwatch project but I must have gone wrong with the logic or something along the way.

Please, find the code below;

```
let time;
const timer = document.getElementById('#timer');
let timeCount = 0;
let timeInterval;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

// function print(txt) {
//     document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = txt;
//   }

//creating minutes and seconds format
function timeToString(counter){
    let hours = counter/3600000;
    let hr = Math.floor(hours);
    let minutes = (hours - hr) * 60;
    let min = Math.floor(minutes); 

    let seconds = (minutes - min) * 60;
    let sec = Math.floor(seconds); 
}

buttons.forEach(function(button){
 console.log(button);
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        const target = event.currentTarget.classList;
        if(target.contains('start')){
            // function start(){
                time = Date.now() - timeCount;
                timeInterval = setInterval(function returnTime(){
                    timeCount = Date.now() - time;
                    console.log(timeToString(timeCount));
                },1000);          
            // }
    
        }else if(target.contains('stop')){
            clearInterval(timeInterval);
    
        }else {
            clearInterval(timeInterval);
            return ('00:00');
            timeCount = 0;
            }
        
    });
    

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is usual for questions to provide an indication of where the problem is, what is going wrong, and what you have tried. Just providing your (long) code makes it hard for us to help

Comment: Can you mention what the output looks like? So we can know what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Since the exact question here was not clear, I decided to just fix the whole thing. I'll include the code but I first want to explain what I did, not just spoonfeed.

- First, the selector for your buttons was incorrect, it was selecting classes instead of the actual tag, so I just removed the '.'.
- Your timeToString(time) function didn't return anything, I added `return hr + "h " + min + "m " + sec + "s";`
- I changed `time` to `timeStarted` to remove confusion. Now, when the start button is clicked, it sets the current time to that variable and then just subtracts that from the current time each update.
- Finally, I added a bit of code to actually update the time on screen: `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeToString(Date.now() - timeStarted);`

```js
let timeStarted;
let timeInterval;
const timer = document.getElementById('#timer');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function timeToString(counter){
    let hours = counter/3600000;
    let hr = Math.floor(hours);
    let minutes = (hours - hr) * 60;
    let min = Math.floor(minutes); 

    let seconds = (minutes - min) * 60;
    let sec = Math.floor(seconds); 
    
    return hr + "h " + min + "m " + sec + "s";
}

buttons.forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        const target = event.currentTarget.classList;
        if(target.contains('start')){
            timeStarted = Date.now();
            timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeToString(Date.now() - timeStarted);
            }, 1000);
        } else if(target.contains('stop')){
            clearInterval(timeInterval);
        }
    });
    

});
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>

<button class="start">start</button>
<button class="stop">stop</button>
```

`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out time for this. I appreciate it.